# Logging into WordPress programatically. Weird post parameters?

Tags: c#, jquery, wordpress, post

I've encountered a problem when trying to login to my WordPress blog with C#.

Normally, when logging into a WordPress blog, there are only 5 parameters I need to send with a POST request. I can easily login when these are my only parameters.

- log
- pwd
- wp-submit
- redirect-to
- testcookie

The problem I'm encountering now is there are extra parameters and I don't know how to send them programmatically in C#. These names and values are not in the  section.

- 2 of them are a 32 character name with 32 character value. (lowercases and numbers)
- 1 is a 8 character name with an empty value.
- 1 is a 12 character name with a 10 character value. (capitals and numbers)

Viewing the page source, I can find the values for the 32 char names, but the names themselves are not there. The following is at the bottom of the source in a script tag:

```
<8 char name here>=escape(document['referrer']);
hf4N='<32 char value here>';
hf4V='<32 char value here>';
```

This is followed by a long jQuery call looking thing:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){var e="#commentform,......
```

What are these? How can I parse this info from the source and continue to login to my WordPress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that bottom jQuery call, I found where two of the parameters came from

```
<8 char>= escape(document['referrer']);
hf4N = '<32 char>';
hf4V = '<32 char>';
$("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "<8 char>").attr("value", <8 char>).appendTo(e);
$("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", hf4N).attr("value", hf4V).appendTo(e);
```

The other 2 came within the javascript from plugins at the top and bottom, respectively. Both using the same method of inserting an input into the form.

```
http://<addr>/wp-content/plugins/wp-spamshield/js/jscripts.php
http://<addr>/wp-content/plugins/wp-spamshield/js/jscripts-ftr-min.js
```